# Registered geofence will not fire entered event twice. Why?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, geofencing

For example on this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geofencing.geofencemonitor.geofences.aspx/) MSDN says :

> Geofences are persisted to disk, so they only need to be added to the system once.

But I could not figured out how to "use" that feature. My app fires entered event for registered geofence only when I clear geofence monitor (`GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Clear();`) and then I recreate them or when the device was restarted.

To understand my problem I have this scenario with official MS UWP geolocation sample:

1. [open UWP geolocation sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geofencing.geofencemonitor.geofences.aspx/)
2. 4th item in menu is: Foreground Geofencing
3. Create new geofence, use set here button
4. New geofence appeared in Registered Geofences box
5. and because I used set here button a few seconds later I got Entered event in Events box
6. Everything is OK
7. but
8. when I close the app and run it again I found created geofence in Registered Geofences box from previous (as expected) but here is my problem - it never fires entered event again

Could you please explain my why? Is theres some "re-register method" which I have to call? Or am I looking at this from bad point of view ? Or is my approach to call `GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Clear();` on every app startup right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your steps, I didn't see you trigger the **Exited** state. If you always stay in the the geofence you've set, the [GeofenceStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geofencing.geofencemonitor.geofencestatechanged) won't be raised when your is running and as the same, the [LocationTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.locationtrigger.aspx) in background task also won't trigger. So you won't get **Entered** state twice. If you leave the geofence first and then when you run your app again, you will get "Entered" event in Events box.

Besides, to make sure the geofence can be used more than once, we need set [Geofence.SingleUse property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263732) to `false` and [Geofence.Duration property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263697) to a large enough time interval or a time interval of 0.

For how to use geofence in UWP apps, please see [Guidelines for geofencing apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/guidelines-for-geofencing) and [Set up a geofence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/set-up-a-geofence). And if you are using Mobile Emulator, you can refer to this blog: [Using the Windows Phone Emulator for testing apps with geofencing](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/05/28/using-the-windows-phone-emulator-for-testing-apps-with-geofencing/).

Comment: Thank you. So is it possible to force to trigger the Exited state after it has come into Entered state (after 10 minutes for example)? Or do I have to do some workaround and play with removing and adding just Entered geofences?

Comment: @HonzaBejvl AFAIK, we can't force to trigger the Exited state. I'm not sure why you need to do this. Usually, a user will not always still in the geofence, the Exited state should be able to be triggered sooner or later. But we can remove the geofence after a period of time by using  Geofence.Duration property. Or we can use a timer (e.g. [ThreadPoolTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer)) to do what we want when it comes into Entered state.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally solved this. I know that usually a user will leave the fence but it is not this case. My app is telling user when there is some bus-stop nearby. I have to use relatively large fence radius so there is  high chance that user will close app in same fence where the app was started. Solution: when geofence enter Entered state I save the geofence's ID, when the fence enter Exited state I delete that saved ID. -> During startup I remove and add all saved fences (usually 0-3) Fortune that I have only 250 fences so that solution is not so expensive.